# Convert .lrc to .srt

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to convert a file from `.lrc` to `.srt` ( SubRip )

I use:

```
if (preg_match("|\[(\d\d)\:(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\](.+)|", $lrcl, $m)) {
    $lines[] = array(
        'time' => "00:{$m[1]}:{$m[2]},{$m[3]}0", // convert to SubRip-style time
        'lyrics' => trim($m[4])
    );  
}

$srt .= "$n\n"
    .  "{$lines[$i]['time']} --> {$nexttime}\n"
    .  "{$lines[$i]['lyrics']}\n\n";
```

I have a problem where the line has more elements :

> [03:51.91][02:58.48]
>
> [03:13.84][03:09.29][03:04.94][03:00.53]Wait for me to come home
>
> [03:16.13][03:11.70][03:07.19][03:02.75]
>
> [01:32.67]Loving can heal

You can see the last element is lyric and the previous is start time.

When I:

```
echo $lines[$i]['time'];
```

The time is missing ( result not true, should be in order ) :

> 00:03:51,910
>
> 00:03:13,840
>
> 00:03:16,130
>
> 00:01:32,670

Here is [`.lrc` file](http://pastebin.com/XV0TUbme)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: My mistake, I edited. Time missing ( relsult not true, should be in order) :

Comment: Where/when is $i defined? Regex matches..

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to repeat the group you use for the time-stamp and make it optional:

```
(\[(\d\d)\:(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\])(?:\[(\d\d)\:(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\])?(?:\[(\d\d)\:(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\])?(?:\[(\d\d)\:(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\])?(.*)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rgNoYA/1).